# How to create folder on internal storage?

Tags: android

I am trying to create folder on internal storage on my app package Debug show that it created successfully but when i check the phone there is no folder 
have tried everything and nothing work

```
getFilesDir();
Enviroment.getDataDirectory();
```

**my method**

```
private String createPath() {
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
        //create new file directory object
        File directory = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),"Images");
        // if no directory exists, create new directory
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        Log.e("path", directory.getPath());
        return directory.getPath();
        // if phone DOES have sd card
    } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
        // search for directory on SD card
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/InstaDown/" + "Images");
        // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
        // results
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }
        Log.e("path", directory.getPath());
        return directory.getPath();
    }// end of SD card checking
    return null;
}
```

Note : external storage is working

Comment: How are you checking on your device? `when i check the phone there is no folder have tried everything and nothing work`

Comment: I reverse the `if  (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null)` to `=!` -- so it operate like no SD then i go to Files >> Internal Storage >> Android >> data >> my package name >> files and looking for Images Files which i created also try to search for it nothing is appear